# How to change title of an ion-icon?

Tags: html, css, ionicons

I'm trying to change the ion-icon title that appears on mouse-hover. 
Example: [image: pic] 
I've tried for at least a couple of hours to find a solution for this. I just don't know how i can access the title element of ion-icon via css to be able to change the content of it to 'Edit' instead of 'Create'. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try disabling ion-icon popup using CSS event blocking and set "title" property on to a parent element.

CSS

```
ion-icon {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or you can create Icon element using the below code as a workaround and set it on a button.

```
const icon = <Icon icon='arrow-right' title={false} />;
return <Button minimal icon={icon} title='Next' />;
```

Details here - https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/2321

Answer (score 7):

disable events:

```
ion-icon {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and wrap icon with span tag using title attribute:

```
<span title="Edit" style="font-size: x-large;">
  <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
</span>
```

Comment: I had to add `line-height: 0` to the span to avoid icon alignment problems, since my icon was smaller than the default line height.  Simple solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 5 - Just wrap it in a div like below:

```
<div (click)="presentActionsPopover($event, obj)" slot="end" title="Actions" size="small">
      <ion-icon name="ellipsis-vertical-outline" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below:**

```
<ion-button title="Create Project">
<ion-icon  name="create"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```